# Makefile replace symlink list of files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu, symlink

With GNU Make, I want to take a list of files and create symbolic links of them in another directory (with the same filenames), but also overwrite any existing link with the same filename.

```
existing_files = $(wildcard dir1/dir2/*.txt)

# The next line shows where I would want to put the symbolic links
symlinks = $(wildcard new_dir1/new_dir2/*.txt)

make_some_links:
# Remove previous symlinks if they share name as existing_files
ifeq ($(notdir $(existing_files)), $(notdir $(symlinks)))
    $(info Removing previous symlinks)
    @rm $(symlinks)
endif
# Loop to link here
```

As an aside, does the above condition attempt to match each element of each list, or does it succeed if only 1 of the elements match?

I can't quite figure out how to loop through in Make, including with `$(foreach)`, so I wrote the following loop to show what I mean in something like Python with the same variable names.

```
for i in len($(existing_files)):
    @ln -s $(existing_files)[i] $(symlinks)[i]
```

Here, the first element in `$(list_files)` is linked to the first element in `$(symlinks)`. Any insight on how to write this loop in Make, or if there is straight-up a better way to approach this would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't done this myself but have you looked into static pattern rules? https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this in stages.

First, to create a symbolic link, and remove a preexisting link of that name, if there is one:

```
ln -fs filename linkname
```

Now to make a list of the existing files:

```
existing_files = $(wildcard dir1/dir2/*.txt)
```

So far, so good. Let's suppose this gives us `dir1/dir2/red.txt dir1/dir2/green.txt`.

```
# The next line shows where I would want to put the symbolic links
symlinks = $(wildcard new_dir1/new_dir2/*.txt)
```

That will give you a list of the things that *already exist* in that directory, which is probably not what you intend. We must construct the list of links we want from the list of files we have:

```
filenames := $(notdir $(existing_files))
symlinks := $(addprefix new_dir1/new_dir2/, $(filenames))
```

Now for a rule or rules to build the symlinks. We could write two explicit rules:

```
new_dir1/new_dir2/red.txt: dir1/dir2/red.txt
    ln -fs dir1/dir2/red.txt new_dir1/new_dir2

new_dir1/new_dir2/green.txt: dir1/dir2/green.txt
    ln -fs dir1/dir2/green.txt new_dir1/new_dir2
```

but that is horribly redundant, and besides we don't know the file names beforehand. First we can remove some of the redundancy by defining a variable and using [the automatic variale `$<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
DEST_DIR := new_dir1/new_dir2

$(DEST_DIR)/red.txt: dir1/dir2/red.txt
    ln -fs $< $(DEST_DIR)

$(DEST_DIR)/green.txt: dir1/dir2/green.txt
    ln -fs $< $(DEST_DIR)
```

Now we can see how to replace these rules with a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
$(DEST_DIR)/%.txt: dir1/dir2/%.txt
    ln -fs $< $(DEST_DIR)
```

Now all we need is a master rule that requires the links:

```
.PHONY: make_some_links
make_some_links: $(symlinks)
```

Comment: There are several problems with this solution. 1) If a link exists already but points to another file it could be considered as up-to-date and thus not replaced. 2) If a directory exists with the same name as a target link exists, `ln` will not do what you expect. 3) You must use the `-r` option of `ln` to create the links relative to the links location. 4) The target directory shall exist before trying to create the links.

Comment: Although this post was very helpful, it lacked the last step I needed. This small thing was not specified in my question, so I am accepting. I have multiple directories for the symlinks AND the original files, so I needed to work on that myself. I duplicated the 2nd-to-last step for each directory. This is probably not ideal, but it works for now, and this is taking too much time. Thanks

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: You're right. I threw this Answer together in a hurry, and began to see the flaws a few minutes after I posted it. By the time I got around to correcting it, you had posted your Answer, which covers all of the same points. I will delete this.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: ...Damn, I can't delete an accepted Answer, even if it's mine.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, when you start designing shell loops in make recipes, you are missing important features of make. Make will naturally "*loop*" over the targets you declare to reach the goals you ask it to reach. And make offers many ways to factorize similar rules.

But in your case where the targets are symbolic links there are several issues to consider:

- If you declare the links as regular targets and if some exist already but point to other files than the ones you want, make could consider them as up-to-date and skip them, instead of replacing them. You must thus find a way to force make to re-create all the links or, at least, those that do not point to the correct file. And the last modification times are not sufficient for this.
- Even with the `-f` option `ln` will not replace an exiting directory (or a link to a directory), instead it will create the link inside the directory. You must thus first delete any directory (or link to a directory) that conflicts with a target link.
- The `ln` command shall be used with the `-sr` options to create symbolic links relative to link location.
- The target directory (`new_dir1/new_dir2`) shall exist before you try to create the first link.

If you don't care re-creating links that are already correct, things are easy:

- declare a phony dummy target (`force`) and make it a prerequisite of all your links to force make re-creating them,
- before creating your links delete existing links, files or directories that conflict with them,
- use the proper `ln` options,
- declare the target directory as an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) of the links and add a rule to create it if it is missing.

The following should do the job:

```
source_dir     := dir1/dir2
link_dir       := new_dir1/new_dir2
existing_files := $(wildcard $(source_dir)/*.txt)
symlinks       := $(patsubst $(source_dir)/%,$(link_dir)/%,$(existing_files))

.PHONY: all force
all: $(symlinks)

$(link_dir)/%: $(source_dir)/% force | $(link_dir)
    rm -rf $@
    ln -sr $< $@

force:;

$(link_dir):
    mkdir -p $@
```

If you want to avoid re-creating the existing correct links, things are more difficult because make needs to know which ones are correct and which ones are not, and this cannot be based on last modification times... But as I suspect that the performance impact of re-creating the existing correct links is negligible I suggest that we don't design a complex solution to a non-existing problem.